# How i can read text file letters and save into array in C

Tags: c

When i cout holder(is char) value, an ambiguity letters shown. how can read letters and save to an array then print them?

```
while (holder=fgetc(fileA) != EOF) {
    cout << holder;
    lenA++;
    temp = (char*) realloc(seqA,lenA*sizeof(char));
    if (temp != NULL) {
        seqA = temp;
        seqA[lenA-1] = holder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you need some parentheses or you'll keep storing the comparison between the result of `fgetc` and `EOF`:

```
while((holder=fgetc(fileA)) != EOF)
      ^                   ^
```

Answer (score 1):

`fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`. This is because `EOF` is larger than the value a char can store (to avoid conflicting with a value in `char`). Therefore, it is likely you are going past the end of the file and reading random data.

Change holder to an `int` and use `(char)holder` when printing it and storing it in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you again to first detect the size of the file by seeking to the end and ftelling the file size, allocatin the memory at once and reading the whole file at once by one call to fread.

see my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173870/number-of-letters-in-a-text-file/15174713#15174713%20previous%20question)